# Eclipse data source explorer not showing Inserted table records (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

After I installed Oracle database 11g, I went to Eclipse `Database Development Perspective` and successfully created a new database connection for Oracle.

[image]

Then I created a new account call "testing" and logged in with this new user "testing" through SQL Plus and created a new table.

```
Enter user-name: testing
Enter password:

SQL> CREATE TABLE TBLSAMPLE (NAME varchar(50), EMAIL varchar(50), AGE integer);
Table created.
```

When refresh the Schema in Eclipse's `Data source explorer`. The table added from `SQL Plus` shows up. **(All is working well so far)**

[image]

I proceeded to insert some records from `SQL Plus` with the same user ("testing").
A check on the table shows that the records were indeed inserted.

```
SQL> SELECT * from tblSample;
...
6 rows selected.
```

**Now the problem is:** The inserted records are not showing up in Eclipse's `Data Source Explorer` despite refreshing the schema & the tables folder.

I created a new `SQL file` and select the entire `tblSample`, and it shows 0 records as well. I then inserted 1 row of record from Eclipse `SQL file`. It does shows up in Eclipse, but it does not affect the 6 rows of records in Oracle `SQL Plus`.

Why are the inserted records not showing up in Eclipse? To troubleshoot the culprit, I created a `NetBeans` project using the same Oracle database and all 6 rows of records does show up in `NetBeans`.

So what could have gone wrong?

Comment: Modifications performed by a session are not visible to others until they are commited. Issue a `commit` after performing these changes.

Comment: @BalazsPapp Thank you for your reply. But if it is not committed, why is it displaying in NetBeans, but not in Eclipse?

Comment: @BalazsPapp I think you are right. I issued a `commit` statement and all records shows up now. You can post your solution below and I will accept it. Now I only wonder why NetBeans doesn't requires the commit to see the updated results yet Eclipse requires it.

Comment: Oracle does not allow you to read dirty data (*).  Your testing with NetBeans must be faulty. (AFAIK - there are ways to read uncommited data but that requires some highly advanced DBMS packages that are designed to be used for 2-phased commits)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifications performed by a session are not visible to others until they are commited. Issue a `commit` after performing these changes.

Comment: Accept and up-voted for your swift response. Even if you don't place a solution here, I've decided to reward you in other ways ;)